# Getting "Undefined variable" AFTER deploying Laravel app on ubuntu16.04

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, deployment

In my app, I have similar to this

```
@extends('layout.master')

<?
$user = auth()->user();
$specialities_store_granted     = $user->can('specialities.store');
?>

@section('top-buttons')
    @if ($specialities_store_granted)
        //.....
    @endif
@stop
```

code on each page which works fine on my local machine. However, after deploying on Ubuntu I get an error on each page similar to this

```
   Undefined variable: specialities_store_granted (View: 
/var/www/....com/resources/views/specialities/specialities.blade.php)
```

What it may be?

Comment: use `<?php`, not `<?`.

Comment: @ryantxr wow! this is it! Thanks !!!!

Comment: Can you explain why does it happen? Is this something special about ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: No. It is a PHP setting. On your ubuntu install it is turned off. Always use `<?php`.

Comment: In blade you can use `@php ... @endphp` - more Laravel way :) https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#php

Comment: Yea I know, it's I just visually prefer <? style. Thanks anyway)

Comment: a small but important note it will be deprecated in php 7.4 and removed in php 8.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `<?` to `<?php`.

There is a PHP setting allow `<?` but that is turned off in your PHP installation.

Note also that this legacy feature will be deprecated and removed.
It only still exists to support really old code. Don't use it.